# React fetch multiple endpoints of API error TypeError: fetch(...).json is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, fetch, try-catch

I am doing a `React.js` project. I am fetching data from an [API](https://www.swapi.tech/) and pass it from the parent component by props. Also, I am using different endpoints of the same API in this children component. I need to match the "characters/people" from the props, with the ones inside  this new endpoint of the same API. I have a function that it seems to work, but I get two errors. The first one is not always, but sometimes in the console it shows error 429 too many API calls. I did a setTimeOut function that it seems it solved. But, now I have another error from the catch that says: TypeError: fetch(...).json is not a function. This is the code:

```
import styles from './MovieDetail.module.css';

const MovieDetail = ({ film }) => {

    const peoples = film.properties?.characters.map(async (characterURL) => {
        try {
            const people = await fetch(characterURL).json().results;
            if (people.ok) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return people;
                }, 1000)
            };
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error('Error peoples', err)
        }
    })
    console.log('peoples MovieDetail', peoples)

    return (
        <div className={styles.card}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <h2>{film.properties?.title}</h2>
                <p>{film.description}</p>
                <p>Release date: {film.properties?.release_date}</p>
                <p>Director: {film.properties?.director}</p>
                <p>Producer: {film.properties?.producer}</p>
                <p>Characters:</p>
                {peoples?.map(people=> (
                    <ul id={styles.list}>
                        <li>{people.properties?.name}</li>
                    </ul>
                ))}
            </div>            
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default MovieDetail;
```

This is the whole code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dream-jg82q?file=/src/components/MovieDetail/index.jsx).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to await the `json()` call separately.
Also, add a state array to store the data to display and call the `fetch` function in a `useEffect` hook:

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

const getPeoples = () => {
  film.properties?.characters.map(async (characterURL) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(characterURL);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.results.ok) {
        // Add new people to `people` array
        setPeople((oldPeople) => [...oldPeople, ...data.results]);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error peoples', err);
    }
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getPeoples();
}, [film]);
```

Comment: Thanks Luca. I called the await separately, but I still having issues. The map in the jsx ddoesn't render anything. I did a console.log(peoples) and it gives me an array of promises undefined. This is the error: [Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios Try with the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through your code, and there are few mistakes, that you're doing.

**First is:**
You are passing your props named as `films` from your parent component and getting as `film` in your child component.

so change this in your `ItemContainer/index.jsx`

```js
return <MovieDetail key={film?.properties?.episode_id} film={film} />;
```

and **Second is:**
you need to await for your json as well:

so change this in your `MovieDetail/Index.jsx`

```js
const peoples = film?.properties?.characters.map(async (characterURL) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(characterURL);
    const people = await response.json().results;
    if (response.ok) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return people;
      }, 1000);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error peoples", err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pradip. I fixed the mistake and I also added the await for the json. However, it doesn't render the map of peoples in the jsx. The console.log(peoples) gives an array of promises undefined. This is the error in the console: [Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: because, peoples return the Promise so you need to do, `Promise.all([peoples])` and also you need to use `useEffect` and `useState` to fetch peoples and store their data in state. And map your data from state.